# WebM format video is not transparent

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor, compile

Blender can export video in WebM format which is supposed to carry an alpha channel. However, I am not getting a transparent video but one with black background.

I have had successful results with Quicktime. But I need WebM format for a specific project.

The results I am getting are really weird. The video has a black background and the output is very weird

I understand that most video players don't play WebM format however it looks like the way I described, even when I import the final video in blender video editor

Here are my settings
[image]

I read in some guides online that the film in render properties should be transparent. So, I did that as well. Not sure if it matters or not